# How to find a differential equation with exponential decay between two values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, initial-value-problems

Given the following the function which describes an exponential decay from A to $\alpha$*A in time with a time constant $\tau$ with $\alpha < 1$:

$$A+(\alpha*A-A)*(1-e^{(-t/\tau)}).$$

How can I find the associated differential equation with initial value A(0) = A. I've added a plot of the function below.

[image: Plot of solution]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Ties

Comment: **Differentiate** it.  If $x(t)= A+ \left(\alpha A- A\right)\left(1- e^{-t/\tau}\right)$ then $x'(t)= \frac{\alpha A- A}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is of the form
$f(t) = u+ve^{wt}$.

Differentiating,
$f'(t) =wve^{wt}$.

Now relate $f$ and $f'$.